# How to create a generic "create photo" code for both iPhone and Android using Appcelerator?

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I am trying to create an application that is capable of creating photos on both Android and iPhone using Appcelerator. The functionality should launch default photo API, create a photo, allow user to either agree with photo, or cancel it, and on successful result save it on the memory card. It is not necessary that photos should be automatically added to the Gallery.

Currently I am using this code which works perfectly for Android :

```
Rf.media.photo = {
  key: 'photo',
  title: 'Photo',
  extension: 'jpg',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  create: function(created) {
    Ti.Media.showCamera({
      // TODO: disallow video for ios
      animated: false,
      saveToPhotoGallery: false,
      showControls: true,
      success: function(media_item) {
  var name = Rf.util.timestamp() + '.' + Rf.media.photo.extension;
  Rf.write_to_new_file(name, media_item.media, function(file) {
    created(file);
  });
      },
    });
  },
};
```

I am looking for ways to tweek this code, so it would work also for iPhone. At the moment it is unresponsive when tested on iPhone 4.
Anyone knows whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the kitchenSink examples for photo and photo gallery, they provide a pretty complete example

Comment: The functionality described in the KitchenSink app does not really fit the description, since (as far as I can see) the file taken by the app is never saved to the SD card or Gallery.